# Show/hide multiple fields based on drop down selection

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I am using SharePoint Calendar and we are using multiple columns and it is 25 columns, in each time when we want to add new record, we have to skip a lot of columns. So using a dropdown list by showing or hiding multiple columns based on my selection would be a good idea.

What I did after discovering below code, I create a dropdown named `Selection` and applied the script code below but however it does not work based on my selection. I will be grateful if you guys could help me on this issue.

Thank you

```
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="/SiteAssets/sputility.js "></script>

<script>

$(document).change(function() {
    var ddlValue = SPUtility.GetSPField('Selection').GetValue();

    if (ddlValue == 'Country') {
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Country');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Colour');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Animal');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
    }

    if (ddlValue == 'Fruit') {
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Fruit');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Colour');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Animal');
    }
    if (ddlValue == 'Animal') {
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Animal');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Colour');
    }

    if (ddlValue == 'Colour') {
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Colour');
    SPUtility.ShowSPField('Animal');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Country');
    SPUtility.HideSPField('Fruit');
    }
});

</script>
```

Comment: Above updated the code @lem.mallari

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you need to do is create a `change()` function linked to your dropdown so that the function triggers every time you change the values. You can do that by doing this:

```
$("your selector for your dropdownfield").change(function() {
    //your actions here
});
```

The next thing you need to do is get the value of the dropdown field then perform the hiding of the fields based from its value. To do that, you need to do the following:

```
var ddlValue = SPUtility.GetSPField('Selection').GetValue();

if (ddlValue == 'Test Value 1') {
    //hide fields for 'Test Value 1'
}
```

So if we combine the two together you will end up with:

```
$("your selector for your dropdownfield").change(function() {
    var ddlValue = SPUtility.GetSPField('Selection').GetValue();

    if (ddlValue == 'Test Value 1') {
        //hide fields for 'Test Value 1'
    }
});
```

You can just add more if conditions within the `change()` function and you should now be able to hide/show fields based on the value of the dropdown.

Let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi @lem.mallari, thanks it is working but when I chose a field that triggers to hide another field causes not showing hidden field again in next selection. I am not sure what causes that.

Comment: Could you update your question and provide your existing code?

Comment: Let's continue discussing in chat - https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169062/show-hide-multiple-fields-based-on-drop-down-selection

Comment: I am unfortunately unable to attend due to having less than 20 reputation marks.

Comment: Oh. OK. Can you clearly explain what is happening? You mentioned "but when I chose a field that triggers to hide another field causes not showing hidden field again in next selection". What do you mean by this?

Comment: Oh okay I just solved, so I have to indicate both Show and Hidefields in all the IF statements. My problem was If I go to dropdown list and choose Country which hides animal field, and then go to dropdown list to choose Animal, it does not show the fields which Country field hides. So I create Show and Hidefields for all. Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Yup that is correct. It would be much cleaner if you create functions for each if statement which shows/hides the fields. That way you just update the function and can reuse it should there be a need in the future.